# hiding an image and its overlay

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image that only appears if it has some content in it's ALT attribute. THis works well using:

```
  img.video[alt=""] {
    display:none;
    height:0px;
}
```

However I want the image to also have an overlay that will also dissappear... the overlay is a play button, but it stays.

```
          <li>
            <img class="video" src="<?php echo $row_rs_dealItem['imagemain']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row_rs_dealItem['video']; ?>">
              <img id="videoLogo" src="images/video.png"/>
            </img>
          </li>
```

Is there a better way to solve this?

thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is, you must use the [adjacent sibling](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) selector, because img elements can't have childs.

The HTML :

```
<li>
    <img class="video" src="..."   alt="...">
    <img class=v src="images/video.png">
 </li>
```

And the CSS :

```
img.video[alt=""], img.video[alt=""] + img.v {
    display:none;
    height:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a class to the parent li when the contents needs to be hided (if there is no alt text in your case). Then use CSS to show/hide the elements you like.